# Spring security - How to use role based authentication for different domains?

Tags: spring, spring-security

There is a project with Spring boot back-end on running on localhost:8080 and 2 front-end angular applications on localhost:4200 (User website) and localhost:4201(Admin website).How can i configure spring security so that it allows only users with role - `ROLE_USER`,`ROLE_ADMIN` in User website and users with role -`ROLE_ADMIN` should have access to Admin Website.

Currently both users are able to access both wesbite.Is there any way to restrict certain domains rather restricting paths(URLs) to users.

Current config -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env; 

    @Autowired
    UserSecurityService useSecurityService;
    
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }
    
    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATHCES= {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/book/**",
            "/user/**",
            "/media/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(useSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATHCES).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and();
        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        
    }
     
      @Bean
      public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionStrategy() {
          return  HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
      }
      
        
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose all of your configurations configured properly, then you can make use of the role restriction mechanism as the below sample :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorize - > {
            authorize
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll() //do not use in production!
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/book/**", "/user/**", "/media/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/website/find", "/main*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/userweb/v1/data/**").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/userweb/v1/info/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/userweb/v1/item/{upc}").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers("/admin/main").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/api/v1/normal")
            .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN", "FOO");
        })
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and().csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: no,i wanted a config  which can prevent particular domains rather than paths ,(eg-ROLE_USER should have access to only localhost:4200 and not to localhost:4201)  , i already know how to config particular paths

Comment: @Codemaster your question about multi-role restriction, anyway it does not matter since every request has its own credential, admin != user

Comment: My question is how to use role based restriction for different domains

Comment: @Codemaster then you can make use of `spring CORS`, or with the configuration level https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: @Codemaster i think you are referring to role based restriction for different domains,it is not possible to restrict certain users to certain domains.A better approach would be to create different path request from different domains(eg - localhost:4200 will send request /user/login and localhost:4201 will send request /admin/login and then you can use the confid Mahmoud has provided )

Comment: @wolf Thank you ,i was not aware that it was not possible.